# How to monitor Netty EventLoopGroup threadpool

Tags: netty, threadpool, monitoring

I have a server built with Netty and its threadpool is based on bossGroup/workerGroup model. Which is the basic Netty server implementation:

```
    EventLoopGroup bossGroup = new NioEventLoopGroup(poolSize);
    EventLoopGroup workerGroup = new NioEventLoopGroup(poolSize);


    ServerBootstrap b = new ServerBootstrap();
    b.group(bossGroup, workerGroup)                 
        .channel(NioServerSocketChannel.class)
        .handler(new LoggingHandler(LogLevel.INFO))
        .childHandler(new TelnetServerInitializer());

    b.bind(PORT);
```

If I would like to monitor activity of the two threadpool bossGroup and workerPool, something like the active thread counts and pool size? How should I do?

For Java's ThreadPoolExecutor, I have the:

```
ThreadPoolExecutor.getActiveCount()
ThreadPoolExecutor.getQueue.size()
```

For EventLoopGroup, it also extends ExecutorService. Is there a way to get those information?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you use `NioEventLoopGroup` / `EpollEventLoopGroup` / `KQueueEventLoopGroup` you can use `SingleThreadEventExecutor.pendingTasks()` :

https://github.com/netty/netty/blob/4.1/common/src/main/java/io/netty/util/concurrent/SingleThreadEventExecutor.java#L308

You can obtain all the executors via:

`EventLoopGroup.iterator()`